# How to validate so that the time is after the current time

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, I want to validate so that the time is after the current time and date. So I coded the validation as follows

```
$validateData = $request->validate([
        'time_start' => ['required', 'date', 'after:today']
    ]);
```

But what I noticed is that `'after:today'` only checks the date and does not care about the time.
How can I validate it so that it checks the time and date?

Comment: Is `after:now` valid?

Comment: Try if `after:created_at` and `after:updated_at` works

Comment: after:now works